# How to save contact's images in local database while fetching contacts from phone in phonegap

Tags: image, cordova, base64, phonegap-plugins

I am fetching contacts from phone along with their images in phonegap.I have to save those images to my local database in Base64 or byte-array, So that later i can send those data to server also.

I am able to convert image into Base64 but this process is synchronous.
Let suppose i have 10 Contacts in my phone in which 5 contacts have image and rest has not.
so when i am applying loop for saving those images,so that time contacts who have images takes time to change images to Base64 mean while contacts who doesn't have images store in database because for these 5 contacts no need to change image to Base64.

So only 5 contacts get inserted in database and i get the Base64 of those 5 contacts after completing the loop.

I want that in loop untill i get the Base64 of any image, loop index should not increase by 1. As i get the Base64 of image after that i should move to next index.

This is the method which i am using for Converting any image to Base64.

```
function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
            alert(url);
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
        img.onload = function(){
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png');
        //alert("URL "+url);
        //alert("dataURL " + dataURL);
        alert(dataURL);

        callback.call(this, dataURL);
         // Clean up
        canvas = null; 
        };
        img.src = url;
    }
```

Can anyone please help me.